# Proving that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}{e^{-(x^2 + y^2)}} = (\int_{\mathbb{R}}{e^{-x^2}})^2$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I'm trying to prove that
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}{e^{-(x^2 + y^2)}} = \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}{e^{-x^2}}\right)^2,$$
provided the first integral exists (it's an exercise of Munkres' *Analysis on Manifolds*).

As usual, I tried to use Fubini's Theorem, but I'm afraid that I can't assure all the hypothesis (or manipulate my problem to use it). But, assume I could use Fubini's. Thus,
\begin{align}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}{e^{-(x^2 + y^2)}} &= \int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}{e^{-(x^2 + y^2)}}dxdy\\&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}{e^{-x^2}e^{-y^2}}dxdy\\&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-y^2}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}{e^{-x^2}}dx\right)dy .\end{align}
As the inner integral does not depend on $y$, we have
\begin{align}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}{e^{-(x^2 + y^2)}} &=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-y^2}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}{e^{-x^2}}dx\right)dy\\&=\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}{e^{-x^2}}dx\right)\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-y^2}dy\right),\end{align}
and this prove the result. How can I improve this proof? Can I restrict my problem over rectfiable compacts that cover all $\mathbb{R}^2$, and then use Fubini?

Comment: The proof looks good to me. Note that since the function is nonnegative, using Fubini doesn't cause problem if you allow $+\infty$ to be the result of the integral.

Comment: Ok. The problem for me is that Munkres does not proved Fubinis theorem for anything but rectangles and simple regions.